# Theorem of the dimension of fibers without irreducible hypothesis

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$ with $Y$ irreducible and $X$ not necessarily irreducible.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Given a morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is it still true that $dim(f^{-1}(y))=0$ or $dim(f^{-1}(y))=\emptyset$ for a *general* $y\in Y$?

I thought this follows from the theorem of the dimension of fibers. But this theorem assumes $X$ to be irreducible as well. So maybe one can restrict to the irreducible components of $X$ and use the theorem there. But what about irreducible components of $X$ of dimension $<n$? Or do we need to make more assumptions for this to be true? A reference would also be great.

Comment: Components of smaller dimension play no role, since their image is contained in a proper subvariety of $Y$ and thus do not contain a general point.

Comment: I do noth think you meant $dim(f^{-1}(y))=\emptyset$, but probably $f^{-1}(y)=\emptyset$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still true, and for a trivial proof as you said you can restrict to irreducible components, and components of dimension less than $n$ still do not create problems, as you can see either by repeating the proof for the equal dimensions or by taking the product of your smaller dimension component with an affine space to reduce to the equal dimension case.